# How should Bin Deployable Assemblies be updated from NuGet packages?

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, bin

I just applied the Nuget patch for ASP.NET MVC4 DisplayModes and with it came a bunch of web dll dependency updates from 2.0.20505.0 to 2.0.20710.0, which have been updated just fine in my packages folder which is in my solution tree, the packages.config file and the .csproj file.

Trouble is though, the build and deploy don't pick up the new versions and just copy the old 20505 versions out of the GAC. Is there something I'm missing about how the packages are referenced? This is VS2010 SP1 and MVC4.

Thanks

Martyn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NuGet packages themselves probably have little to do with the behavior you're seeing.  The package.config file does have a version number for each package, and if that information is up-to-date, then NuGet is going to restore those versions of the packages when it's asked.

The problem is more likely to be with the deployment settings you're using, of which I know little.  Of course, I should point out that build 20505 -- the build you have in your GAC -- is a release candidate version of MVC 4, and that it's probably in your interest to go ahead and upgrade to the final build, which has since been released.

HTH,
Clay

Comment: Thanks Clay, I think you're right. NuGet is doing its job and updating the local packages and the deployment is also doing what it should. I think my problem is getting the build to pick up the local packages rather than the GAC copies. I take your point and will try upgrading my GAC installed set. Thanks again

Comment: That was fun! v2.0.20710 MVC4 needed but did not ship with Microsoft WebPages OAuth library of the same version. This seems to be a new dependency, that bombs at runtime. The error makes it appear that its just the OAuth core that's missing, but it's actually the AspNet pacakage that is needed, that pulls all the right assemblies in with it. Phew!